# Could somebody explain me,what these scripts are doing in plain english?

Tags: javascript

I have a Java script used to give me some charts.

the code is below.

```
data:text/html,<html>
<hhref="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11433463/habrahabr/starfield.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11433463/habrahabr/js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11433463/habrahabr/js/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11433463/habrahabr/js/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
     TweenMax.to($('#bg1'), 9, {css:{backgroundPosition: "-314 0px"}, repeat:-1, ease:Linear.easeNone});
     TweenMax.to($('#bg2'), 30, {css:{backgroundPosition: "-269 30px"}, repeat:-1, ease:Linear.easeNone});
});
</script>
<div class="starfield" id="sample">
     <div class="stars" id="bg1"></div>
     <div class="stars" id="bg2" style="background-position: 20 30px"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><head>    <title>Speedometer</title>    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:300,300' type='text/css'>        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/vendor/d3.v3.min.js"></script>    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/vendor/polymer/PointerEvents/pointerevents.js"></script>    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/vendor/polymer/PointerGestures/pointergestures.js"></script>    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/iopctrl.js"></script>        <script>        var TableauInput = "3201,49";var TableauParse = JSON.parse("[" + TableauInput + "]");        </script>        <style>        body {            font: 16px arial;            background-color: #515151;        }        .unselectable {            -moz-user-select: -moz-none;            -khtml-user-select: none;            -webkit-user-select: none;            -ms-user-select: none;            user-select: none;        }        /* css formats for the gauge */        .gauge .domain {            stroke-width: 2px;            stroke: #fff;        }        .gauge .tick line {            stroke: #fff;            stroke-width: 2px;        }                .gauge line {            stroke: #fff;        }        .gauge .arc, .gauge .cursor {            opacity: 0;        }        .gauge .major {            fill: #fff;            font-size: 20px;            font-family: 'Play', verdana, sans-serif;            font-weight: normal;        }                .gauge .indicator {            stroke: #EE3311;            fill: #000;            stroke-width: 4px;        }        /* css formats for the segment display */        .segdisplay .on {            fill: #00FFFF;        }        .segdisplay .off {            fill: #00FFFF;            opacity: 0.15;        }    </style></head><body>    <div>        <span id="speedometer"></span>    </div>        <script>                    var svg = d3.select("#speedometer")                .append("svg:svg")                .attr("width", 300)                .attr("height", 300);        var gauge = iopctrl.arcslider()                .radius(120)                .events(false)                .indicator(iopctrl.defaultGaugeIndicator);        gauge.axis().orient("in")                .normalize(true)                .ticks(12)                .tickSubdivide(3)                .tickSize(10, 8, 10)                .tickPadding(5)                .scale(d3.scale.linear()                        .domain([0, 160])                        .range([-3*Math.PI/4, 3*Math.PI/4]));        var segDisplay = iopctrl.segdisplay()                .width(80)                .digitCount(6)                .negative(false)                .decimals(0);        svg.append("g")                .attr("class", "segdisplay")                .attr("transform", "translate(130, 200)")                .call(segDisplay);        svg.append("g")                .attr("class", "gauge")                .call(gauge);        segDisplay.value(TableauParse[0]);        gauge.value(TableauParse[1]);        </script></body>ead>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link >
```

Could some body guide me in understanding why use certain links in the script?

like `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11433463/` and what does script does.

thanks!

Comment: They're jQuery and GreenSock tweening libraries (libraries used for scripted animation). They let the code directly embedded in the other `<script>` tags to function. From the looks of it, they just animate the `background-position` on load.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that as your application gets larger, it'll get difficult to maintain; now, if you decouple these things into different files, it'll be better for you as a developer as it'll be really easy to manage.

All the `script` tags which end in `.js`, they import such JavaScript files; each containing some logic.

Imagine it like this: if you have to make something to eat, you gradually add the ingredients, to get the composition you want; you don't put it at once. Similar is the case with software, if you have a huge web application, it'll be smarter for you if you break the code down into small individual chunks, and then use it. This will improve the maintainability of the code as well.

So, for example, if you have a 20 classes (classes are devil's synonym in JS), you can save these in 20 individual files, as it'll be easier to know which file contains which class rather than making spaghetti code and pasting all the code in just one file.

The first couple of `script` tags import other libraries/code blocks; next you have some jQuery code, and lastly some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The links in the `<head>` refer the document to other sources of information:

I.E.: `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` is routing the document to the jQuery library so that you can write jQuery in you script, in stead of just JavaScript (i.e. `$(document).ready( function(){});`